# Lamda functions - Como faço um loop em AWS-StepFunctions - com Nodejs?

Tags: node.js, expressões-lambda, amazon-aws

Tenho uma função lambda, F1, em Nodejs cujo o principal objetivo é ler o conteúdo de um arquivo que é depositado no S3 através de um outro processo.

Digamos q nesse arquivo existam 10 produtos.
Eu preciso fazer um loop através desses produtos a chamar a função F2 10 vezes.

Como eu implemento esse processo com [StepFunctions](https://aws.amazon.com/step-functions/)?

Comment: Seria [igual a esse exemplo](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/tutorial-create-iterate-pattern-section.html)?

Comment: É sim. Então parece q são 3 funções. O iterator é uma função separada. EU estava imaginando 2 funções. Uma para recuperar e fazer o loop e outra função para fazer a tarefa. posta a solução.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Segundo a [documentação](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/tutorial-create-iterate-pattern-section.html) você pode criar um Lambda Function que funciona como um "Iterator":

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ex:

```
exports.iterator = function iterator (event, context, callback) {
  let index = event.iterator.index
  let step = event.iterator.step
  let count = event.iterator.count

  index += step

  callback(null, {
    index,
    step,
    count,
    continue: index < count
  });
}
```